# Photoshop Slices - Add Objects over Images

Tags: html, css, photoshop

So, I made a design for a website in Photoshop and exported the website into HTML & Images. I messed around with it a bit and made it so that the menu items were click-able and when you hover, the text will change, and little things like that.

What I am wondering is how would I have a slice that is essentially just an image with a random colour for example, and be able to place stuff on top of it like buttons or text.

Code:

```
<td colspan="3">
    <img src="images/index_17.png" width="395" height="90" alt=""></td>
```

This is an example of a specific slice I want to place text on top of and be able to change the text whenever I want.

Has anybody ever done this before or have any clue how to do it easily without messing up all of the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to target a specific cell to place and style content your best bet is to call it out in the code by giving it a **unique id**. Once your element has an ID you can **use CSS** to specifically affect the elements you place inside.

Because you're using the slice tool in Photoshop, it by default adds the sliced image into the table cell. Before you can place text in there, you will have to move that inserted image to be a background image instead. The thing to note is once you do that, the `TD` element will not know what size it should be so you will have to explicitly set that to be the size of the image you're moving.

For example using the code you posted you could do something like this:

```css
table {
  border: 1px dotted #333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  }

/* Anything in that cell you would like styled, prepend it with the ID you gave the cell */

td#styled-cell {
  height: 90px;
  width:395px;
  /*background-image: url("images/index_17.png"); */ /*Uncomment this line and update this URL to match where you have your images in relation to your CSS file */
  background-color: #999;
  }

td#styled-cell h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: lightblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }

td#styled-cell p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  }

td#styled-cell a,
td#styled-cell a:link {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: pink;
  }

td#styled-cell a:visited,
td#styled-cell a:hover,
td#styled-cell a:active {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <!-- This is just to show you how it looks in a table, these would be replaced by the other rows and cells photoshop created -->
        Other Example Cell
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" id="styled-cell">
      <h2> Example Styled Text</h2>
      <p> This is an <a href="#"> Example Link</a></p>
      <p>Example Paragraph with no link.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response! I tried implementing it into my webpage, but it through off all the other slices and everything is just jumbled for some reason. I could pastebin the code that I have if you'd like!

Comment: Totally! Paste bin it and I will take a look. I bet there is one small thing thats causing it all to shift. Tables can be so finicky like that.

Comment: Looking at what you have, if you change the 3 bits in the css to

`table {
  border: 0px solid #333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  }
td {
  border: 0px solid #999;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  }
  img {
   border: 0px solid #fff;
  }`

It should lineup again. Without your images I am just going off of what the image sizes are saying @LunarCP! Good Luck